# Finish application after 15 minutes in background

Tags: java, android

How to finish application after 15 minutes, when user minimized?

When user exit from the application without finish it, then user turn back after some time network of application is not working. For work need to restart the application.

I want to trigger when the app becomes at the background and then with timer finish application.

Or how to know when the application is paused, not an activity?

Lifecycle of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Make one *BaseActivity* which is parent of all of your *activities*.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Thread t = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (t != null) {
            try {
                if (t.isAlive()) {
                    t.interrupt();
                    t.join();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            t = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(15 * 60 * 1000);
                     finishAffinity();
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Now extends *BaseActivity* in all of your activity class like below sample,

```
public class ClassTest extends BaseActivity {
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: When I open new activity from mainActivity, onPause method runs, and exit application. I think the above code must not be work between activities

Comment: No, if your `MainActivity` pause for 15 minutes then exit otherwise not.

Comment: I think the above code should not be work between activities. I want to trigger when application at background

Comment: Yes. I create BaseActivity as you say. Then extend BaseActivity for all activities. But the problem was when I pass to second activity from first activity application exits after 15 min.

Comment: Make Thread variable static like, `private static Thread t = null;`

Comment: For testing set sleep time = 30 seconds like `sleep(30 * 1000);`, so you don't have to wait for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ProcessLifecycleOwner to check your app state. It supports library version 26+.

```
    //Check if app is in background
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == 
    Lifecycle.State.CREATED;

    //Check if app is in foreground
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
```

Here is the dependecy of [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner). For more details visit [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#lifecycle)

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData).
    //     Support library depends on this lightweight import
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version" // use kapt for Kotlin
}
```

Comment: What if API under 26?